# UI5 disable internationalisation

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I started a new application on the SAP HANA Cloud platform. However when I start it i get the following errors:

```
GET https://webidetesting5949052-p1940909951trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/messagebundle_de_DE.properties 404 (Not Found)
GET https://webidetesting5949052-p1940909951trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/webapp/i18n/i18n_de_DE.properties 404 (Not Found)
GET https://webidetesting5949052-p1940909951trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/webapp/i18n/i18n_de.properties 404 (Not Found)
and so on....
```

However I never started to use i18n and I just want to disable it. I cant find anything in the manifest and I am not loading a i18n model anymore.

How can I resolve this issue? I dont want to use i18n, as it just clutters my code.

Comment: I won't add this as an answer (I don't know if it's possible to stop the framework from automatically looking for these i18n models) but as a FYI, I've had these errors in virtually every UI5 project I've created. In the Web IDE, I think it asks you for a default language at some point in the wizard. It has never caused any issues for me. If your code is not working as planned, it probably comes from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The first missing file is from within the framework. Some of the controls in `sap.m` have translatable text, and afaik there is nothing you can do about it.

The other lines suggest that you are instantiating an i18n model somewhere. Check your `manifest.json` or `Component.js` or `neo-app.json` for such an entry. These are the files where you'd normaly setup your models, including the i18n model.

**Edit:** It seems like you are using the WebIDE. To remove i18n from manifest.json, switch to *Code Editor*

[image]

If you don't want to use i18n in your code, don't use it. But the code of the framework itself heavily relies on that feature and no hardcoded strings are stored inside a `.js` file. If there actually was a way to disable i18n, then for example the `sap.m.DatePicker` wouldn't work anymore, since all strings for months and days are stored in one of the property files.

---

Btw I think having your logic (JS code) separated from content (i18n strings) is awesome and quite the opposite of cluttered code. All big mobile platforms (Android, iOS) and probably alot more frameworks support that feature. But that's just my 2 cents.

---

**TL;DR** don't instantiate your own i18n model, ignore the framework's errors

Comment: Thx. At the moment we have all our texts in the model and it is such a small demo app, that i don't want to use i18n, just to keep it simpler. However the errors are annyoing :).